# Why my Transaction doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have a method (with `WebMethod` attribute), I define a transaction, in my method and in my transaction I call 2 stored procedures, first one is `GetAllBook` :

```
select * 
from Book_TBL 
where IsActive = 'True'
```

and second one is `updateBook` :

```
update Book_TBL 
set IsActive = 'False' 
where IsActive = 'True'
```

and my method :

```
 public struct BOOK
 {
        public string BOOK_NAME;
        public string BOOK_DESC;          
 }

[WebMethod]
public static List<BOOK> GetMyBooks()
{
    using (TransactionScope _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
    {
        string _connString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
        _conn.Open();

        SqlCommand _com = new SqlCommand();
        _com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _com.CommandText = "GetAllBook";
        _com.Connection = _conn;

        SqlDataAdapter bookdataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_com);
        DataSet bookDS = new DataSet();
        bookdataAdapter.Fill(bookDS, "Book_TBL");

        List<BOOK> bookList = new List<BOOK>();
        _conn.Close();

        BOOK book;

        foreach (DataRow dr in bookDS.Tables["Book_TBL"].Rows)
        {
            book = new BOOK();
            book.BOOK_NAME = dr["book_name"].ToString();
            book.BOOK_DESC = dr["book_desc"].ToString();
            bookList.Add(book);
        }

        SqlCommand updateCommand= new SqlCommand();
        _conn.Open();
        updateCommand.CommandText = "updateBook";
        updateCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        updateCommand.Connection = _conn;
        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _conn.Close();

        return bookList;
   }
}
```

When I run the project `myMethod` gives me the list of books which have `IsActive = True` but it did not update my table! What is the problem?

Comment: Do you see any error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call [`TransactionScope.Complete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the equivalent of a commit. Without it, the using blocks disposes it and that's equivalent to a rollback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't knoe what are you really want to do with a such deeply nested method but you should put everything in place first:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

    public static List<Book> GetMyBooks()
    {
        var bookList = new List<Book>();
        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            const string connString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (var com = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.CommandText = "GetAllBook";
                    com.Connection = conn;

                    using (var bookdataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
                    {
                        using (var bookDataSet = new DataSet())
                        {
                            bookdataAdapter.Fill(bookDataSet, "Book_TBL");

                            foreach (DataRow dr in bookDataSet.Tables["Book_TBL"].Rows)
                            {
                                bookList.Add(new Book
                                {
                                    Name = dr["book_name"].ToString(),
                                    Description = dr["book_desc"].ToString()
                                });
                            }

                            using (var updateCommand = new SqlCommand())
                            {
                                updateCommand.CommandText = "updateBook";
                                updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                updateCommand.Connection = conn;
                                updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            transactionScope.Complete();

            return bookList;
        }
    }
```

And as mentioned the other you have to manually commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the class `SqlTransaction` like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
{
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //some code
        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```